# Substrate Blockchain - Change block structure

Tags: blockchain, substrate

I'm trying to modify the block structure for a blockchain based on Substrate that I'm trying to develop. In particular I would like to add a vector in the header and another one inside the body of the block. Does someone know how it is possible to do that?

I'm a newbie in Substrate :'(

Thanks in advance to everyone who will contribute!

Answer (score 4):

The block and header type in Substrate are generic.

The header needs to implement https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/latest/sp_runtime/traits/trait.Header.html and the block needs to implement https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/latest/sp_runtime/traits/trait.Block.html.

Substrate itself provides two types for that already https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/latest/sp_runtime/generic/struct.Block.html and https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/latest/sp_runtime/generic/struct.Header.html.

When you setup your blockchain, which you mainly do through the runtime you can choose these types.

Comment: Let's say that I need those data. Then I also need to add some methods that need to be called by the blockchain during the consensus. How can I do that? Do I have to modify all of the methods which require an in instance of the Block trait? And would you suggest any tutorial which shows how to do that?

Comment: What kind of data do you want to attach to a block?

Comment: I want to add a vector, storing the results of some challenges whose IDs are published by the block producer in the block itself and which are then updated by the other block validators

Answer (score 1):

If you're after including some data for each block then it's called an Inherent extrinsic ( https://docs.substrate.io/v3/concepts/extrinsics/#inherents ) and would not have a fee associated with it.

Header is a type defined in your runtime so you can change it to include any additional data that you'd like. Search for this definition:

```rust
pub type Header = generic::Header<BlockNumber, BlakeTwo256>;
```

See it in context here:
https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/ad7ce8e3dabb2d1f8f4b4094db5b0e754760e9be/runtime/src/lib.rs#L75